# How to test jinja2 regex_replace ansible filters in python?

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

Let's check the regex_replace. It's working in my Ansible plays, but not in ipython :

```
from jinja2 import Template
Template(" {{ zones | map('regex_replace', '(.*)', '\1') | join(',') }} ").render(zones=['z1','z2','z3'])
```

Throws :
`TemplateRuntimeError: No filter named 'regex_replace'.`

Second attempt:

```
from jinja2_ansible_filters.core_filters import regex_replace
env = jinja2.Environment()
env.filters["regex_replace"] = regex_replace

In [55]: env.from_string(" {{ zones | map('regex_replace', '(.*)', '\1') | join(',') }} ").render(zones=['z1','z2','z3'])
Out[55]: ' \x01\x01,\x01\x01,\x01\x01 '
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not, "How to use jinja2 ansible filters in python?"; you've already figured that out -- your second example is doing exactly the right thing. Your problem is specifically with the `regex_replace` module, and in particular with the use of backreferences in the replacement string.

Your first problem is just basic Python syntax: when you write `\1` in a normal string, that means "the byte with hex character `0x01`". So your `regex_replace` expression replaces all occurrences of `(.*)` with `0x01`...which explains your output. Well, partially; you also need to anchor your regular expression (`^(.*)$`), otherwise it matches the empty string at the end of each line, leading to twice as many replacements as you would expect.

But back to backreferences...what's the correct syntax? A problem is that your string will go through multiple steps of processing; if we try the obvious...

```
"{{ zones | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '\\1') | join(',') }} "
```

...we get the same output. This suggests we just need to escape enough times to avoid the unwrapping. It turns out that this works:

```
"{{ zones | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '\\\\1') | join(',') }} "
```

We can simplify things a little by using a raw string (`r"..."`):

```
r"{{ zones | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '\\1') | join(',') }} "
```

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer larsks,

That's exactly that. The full working code:

import jinja2
from jinja2_ansible_filters.core_filters import regex_replace
env = jinja2.Environment()
env.filters["regex_replace"] = regex_replace
env.from_string(r"{{ zones | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '\\1') | join(',') }}").render(zones=['z1','z2','z3'])

Thanks for the heads-up.